# @for loops in styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to find a method in the styled-components documentation to create a loop. For example can I achieve this `scss` loop in styled-components?

```
@for $i from 0 through 20 {
  #loadingCheckCircleSVG-#{$i} {
    animation: fill-to-white 5000ms;
    animation-delay: ($i - 1.5) * 1s;
    fill: white;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I believe styled-components is mainly js. So, use [js for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) for that

Answer (score 36, accepted):

We don't have support for iteration syntaxes from scss at this time. However, since styled-components accepts JS interpolations, you can just write a simple JS function to make the desired CSS and drop it in.

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

function createCSS() {
  let styles = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i += 1) {
     styles += `
       #loadingCheckCircleSVG-${i} {
         animation: fill-to-white 5000ms;
         animation-delay: ${i - 1.5}s;
         fill: white;
         opacity: 0;
       }
     `
  }

  return css`${styles}`;
}

const Thing = styled.div`
  ${createCSS()};
`
```

Comment: what if i want to pass props: ?? ` ${props=> createCSS(props)}` is not working

Comment: If you do interpolations inside styles you'll need to use the `css` helper.